# Passed parameter to reference model in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm iterating from an array of JSON objects and would like to update the value of a item on change of an input field. I passed the item it should reference to inside the function call but it seems that the model is not being update along with it. The snippets of my code can be seen below:

```js
peopleObject = [
  {name: "Alice", address: "Tokyo", isModified: false},
  {name: "Bob", address: "Manila", isModified: false}
]
formModified(isModified): void {
  isModified = true;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let person of peopleObject; let i=index">
  <input [(ngModel)]="person.name" (ngModelChange)="formModified(person.isModified)" placeholder="{{person.name}}" class="form-control">
  <input [(ngModel)]="person.address" (ngModelChange)="formModified(person.isModified)" placeholder="{{person.address}}" class="form-control">
  <button (click)="savePersonDetails(person.name)" [disabled]="!person.isModified">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: let say you want to change the name of the person, so when you change it from the input field you want to update that name in the peopleObject object right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is subscribe to its input change. You can implement it this way:

```
<input [ngModel]="person.name"                             // Property Binding; Removing the event binding ()
       (ngModelChange)="person.isModified = true"   // Event Binding; directly change the person.isModified to true w/o calling the function
       [placeholder]="person.name"                         // You can also use property binding here [] if you have a dynamic value to assign
       class="form-control">
```

Had created a Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-ngmodel-detect-input-change-assign) for you reference.

**Default name: Alice, when i added 's' - its isModified is changed to true**

[image: Demo]

Comment: it isn't working for me :( isModified is not updating in the model

Comment: May I know if what you are trying to do is subscribe to whatever input change it occurs, it will call the formModified function ? if that's the case, i had updated my answer

Comment: yes that's the idea :) i tried `(input)` but it isn't changing the model as well

Comment: had updated my answer and provided a stackblitz link for you reference. What you're lacking was to set 'this' on your isModified inside the formModified function. Dont forget to initialize isModified at the top of you component's constructor

Comment: I'm iterating through an array of JSON objects so I can't use `this` :( I have updated my question to include sample data

Comment: Had updated the stackblitz link with peopleObject iteration. the isModified of each person is now updated once the ngModel is changed :)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thiawx